# Find recently modified image files in subdirectories on external volume

Tags: finder, spotlight, folders, search, disk-volume

I recently modified some JPGs in a complex directory structure on an external volume on MacOS Catalina. The format of the files was DSC_####.jpg or _DSC####.jpg. I want to find all such files and sort the results by date modified.

Finder's search feature wouldn't return any results at all when using it through CMD+F on the common root directory of the directories where the changes were made and selecting that directory instead of "This Mac". It seems spotlight may not finished indexing this fairly large volume, or indexing may be disabled.

I got this to work exactly as I wanted to through [EasyFind  by DEVONThink](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware). I am not associated with them in any way. I have used EasyFind before and after a reinstall, I was wondering would there would be a native way to do this?[image]

Comment: The native way is the command line utility find. Finder uses Spotlight which is faster but does not index all files.

Comment: The power of the command line! A carefully crafted `find` _command_ piping it to `sort` can produce similar output, not the exact same output, e.g.: `find .  -type f -regex '.*DSC.*\.jpg' -ls | sort -k10`